# Remove separator from breadcrumb

Tags: theming

How can I remove the `<` from the breadcrumb I tried `implode('<', $value['data'])` but no luck

```
   function bootstrap_fit_breadcrumb($variables) {
            $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

            if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
              //$breadcrumb[] = drupal_get_title();
              $breadcrumbs = '<ul class="breadcrumbs_list">';

              $count = count($breadcrumb) - 1;

              foreach ($breadcrumb as $key => $value) {
                  if ($key==0) {
                    $breadcrumbs .= '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
                  } else {
                   $breadcrumbs .= '<li><span></span>' . $value['data'] . '</li>';

                  }
              }
              $breadcrumbs .= '</ul>';
              return $breadcrumbs;
      }
   }
```

**displaying**

```
Home < Financial Services
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed this page?

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7

Also, what theme are you using? I would check the base theme to make sure that it isn't preprocessing the breadcrumbs itself. If so, you'll need to make sure you are calling the appropriate function in order to override the breadcrumb settings.

Comment: yes that's where I got the `implode()` method from... but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Super simple solution: use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). In page.tpl.php replace

```
print $breadcrumb;
```

with

```
print str_replace(" < ", "  ", $breadcrumb);
```

or

```
print str_replace(" < ", " > ", $breadcrumb);
```

**NOTE**: I assume that '`<`' is surrounded by specific pattern otherwise `str_replace` will remove all opening parenthesis of html tags in $breadcrumb variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal 8:** I found a *breadcrumb.html.twig* file in my theme. The separator was coded into the theme (Businessgroup Zymphonies Theme). After removing it from the template, you can add a custom separator using CSS. Something like this:

```
.breadcrumb li:not(:last-child):after {
   content: ">"
}
```